Go Fyne unable to show dialog
I am running a project in Go on vs code, when I run it, printing content outputs to the terminal. I want to be able to fork x children where each child process can present their own dialog and out put data to it. I found fyne is an easy UI for Go and when I run runApp() a small dialog appears. I can't figure out how to concurrently open multiple dialogs, resize them, and log/print text to them. Every child process should be able to print any text to their specific dialog at any time.
For some reason when main gets ran nothing happens, maybe I am using to go routine wrong.
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "os"
   "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
   "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
   "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
   // Fork 3 child processes
   for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
       go runApp()
   }
}

// Child process code
func runApp() {
   a := app.New()
   w := a.NewWindow("Hello")

   hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
   w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
       hello,
       widget.NewButton("Hi!", func() {
           hello.SetText("Welcome :)")
       }),
   ))

   w.ShowAndRun()
}


You can only run a single GUI app in a process. The way to do what you want is to launch the goroutines and show multiple windows from a single app. The app would be run at the end of your main() by calling a.Run() instead of w.ShowAndRun().
See https://docs.fyne.io/started/windows.html

Thank you so much, can you have a glance at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79151872/go-exit-embedded-goroutines

Using @Andy.xyz 's suggestion I created the code below which does exactly what my question tries to implement:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    // Create the main application instance
    a := app.New()

    // Fork 3 child windows
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go runApp(a, i+1)
    }

    // Start the application (blocks until the last window is closed)
    a.Run()
}

func runApp(a fyne.App, id int) {
    title := fmt.Sprintf("Custom Window %d", id)
    w := a.NewWindow(title)

    // Set the window size
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(400, 300))

    // Create label and buttons
    hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
    stopButton := widget.NewButtonWithIcon("Stop tasks", theme.CancelIcon(), func() {
        fmt.Println("Stopping tasks for window", id)
        hello.SetText("Tasks stopped.")
    })

    // Style the stop button to be red
    stopButton.Importance = widget.HighImportance

    // Create a checkout label
    checkoutCount := widget.NewLabel("0 checkouts")
    checkoutCount.TextStyle = fyne.TextStyle{Bold: true}
    checkoutCount.Alignment = fyne.TextAlignCenter

    // Arrange content in a vertical box layout
    content := container.NewVBox(
        container.NewHBox(stopButton, checkoutCount), // Place checkout count next to stop button
        hello,
        widget.NewButton("Hi!", func() {
            hello.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("Welcome :) (Window %d)", id))
        }),
    )

    // Wrap the content in a scroll view
    scrollableContent := container.NewVScroll(content)

    // Set the scrollable content as the window's content and show the window
    w.SetContent(scrollableContent)
    w.Show()

    // Call logToWindow function 3 seconds after showing the window
    time.AfterFunc(3*time.Second, func() {
        logToWindow(hello, id)
        updateCheckoutCount(checkoutCount, id) // Start updating checkout count
    })
}

func logToWindow(label *widget.Label, id int) {
    message := fmt.Sprintf("Log message from window %d", id)
    label.SetText(message + "\n" + label.Text)
    time.AfterFunc(1*time.Second, func() {
        logToWindow(label, id)
    })
}

func updateCheckoutCount(label *widget.Label, id int) {
    count := 0
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    go func() {
        for range ticker.C {
            count++
            label.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("%d checkouts", count))
        }
    }()
}

